# Could not read .config parameters in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a simple question about how can makefile read in a varibale is set in .config file.

for example i have CONFIG_a=y CONFIG_b and CONFIG_c as three variables in .config of my linux configuration . I have a Makefile which should define a variable depending upon which CONFIG_X is set

```
if CONFIG_A
DFLAGS=-DABC
if CONFIG_B
DFLAGS=-DBCD
if CONFIG_C
DFLAGS=-DCDE
```

How could i achieve this in make file.

I tried

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_A),y)
DFLAGS=-DABC
else
ifeq ($(TARGET_B),y)
DFLAGS=-DBCD
else
DFLAGS=-DCDE
endif
endif
```

THIS could not help each time -DCDE is set.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What you tried looks completely different from what you want. And what is the `THIS` in your last sentence?

Comment: THIS means this kind of setup in make file.

Comment: Let me explain you more details.
i have a make file who needs -DABC or -DXYZ flags to be set depending upon either of  CONFIG_PACKAGE_xxx or CONFIG_PACKAGE_abc is set. i need to know hoe could i write make file to do this before i compile.

Comment: What I do not understand is why your config file sets `CONFIG_X` variables while your makefile tests `TARGET_X` variables. What is the relationship between them?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using GNU Make.

Let's assume a that exactly one of `CONFIG_a`, `CONFIG_b`, `CONFIG_c` must be *set*
in `foo.config`, by a line of the form:

```
CONFIG_(a|b|c)\s*=\s*y
```

where `\s*` means *0 or more spaces*.

Then you can parse the setting and conditionally set `DFLAGS` as shown:-

**Makefile**

```
CONFIG := $(filter CONFIG%=y,$(shell tr -d ' ' < foo.config))
ifneq ($(words $(CONFIG)),1)
$(error Exactly one CONFIG_? must be set)
endif
ifeq ($(CONFIG),CONFIG_a=y)
DFLAGS:=-DABC
endif
ifeq ($(CONFIG),CONFIG_b=y)
DFLAGS=-DBCD
endif
ifeq ($(CONFIG),CONFIG_c=y)
DFLAGS=-DCDE
endif
$(info CONFIG=$(CONFIG))

.PHONY: all

all:
    @echo DFLAGS=$(DFLAGS)
```

With:

**foo.config (1)**

```
CONFIG_a = y
CONFIG_b
CONFIG_c
```

you'll get:

```
$ make
CONFIG=CONFIG_a=y
DFLAGS=-DABC
```

With:

**foo.config (2)**

```
CONFIG_a = n
CONFIG_b=y
CONFIG_c
```

you'll get:

```
$ make
CONFIG=CONFIG_b=y
DFLAGS=-DBCD
```

With:

**foo.config (3)**

```
CONFIG_a = y
CONFIG_b
CONFIG_c=y
```

you'll get:

```
$ make
Makefile:3: *** Exactly one CONFIG_? must be set. Stop.
```

And with:

**foo.config (4)**

```
CONFIG_a = n
CONFIG_b
CONFIG_c
```

again:

```
$ make
Makefile:3: *** Exactly one CONFIG_? must be set. Stop.
```

To understand how it works see:-

- [man tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)
- [8.13 The shell Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) in [the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)
- [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) in the GNU Make manual.